# spring cloud sidecar timeout configuration

Tags: spring-cloud

I am using sidecar in spring cloud to retrieve internal apis from nodeJS, but I have met an issue. One method is pretty slow, and when I use sidecar I got exception like this:

{
    "timestamp": 1439073758177,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException",
    "message": "Forwarding error"
}

This api call is taking longer time than others, so how can I adjust timeout settings for side car?

Thanks

Comment: How are you making the call?  I'm a bit confused by "using sidecar in spring cloud to retrieve"...

Answer (score 1):

I found that adding this to my configuration solved timeout problem:

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.semaphore.maxConcurrentRequests: 20
ribbon:
  ConnectTimeout: 10000
  ReadTimeout: 60000
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your hystrix isolation strategy, Spring cloud enforce SEMAPHORE strategy, so property "**hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds**" has nothing to do

property **"ribbon.ReadTimeout"** will do the job for you